# List View Naming and Visibility Control

Tags: administration, permissions, list-view, custom-view

I've done some research and the closest I have found to **CONTROLLING creation of List Views** is here:   [Restrict List View Creation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000187425).

I'd like to **stop some profiles** from being able to create List Views that are visible to All Users (so they can only create their own private lists).  I've never done this, and cannot find a setting for it.

[image]

I'd also like to investigate how to force a naming convention - or possibly **force a PREfIX to show up on user-created Views**, so when they DO make them public (all), we see SOMETHING akin to the below.  Biggest issue with a prefix is if/when they edit the list name, now to make sure a prefix still exists and is not duplicated.  I hate it when there are 100+ views publicly visible.  *I'd PREFER ti possibly be able to show another field NEXT TO the view name (like created-by) in the actual picklist dropdown.*

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Permission Sets, in the System Permissions section, there is a Permission Name called "Create and Customize List Views" and one called "Manage Public List Views". For Profiles, it's the same two settings and they're under Administrative Permissions when editing the Profile.

As far as the naming convention goes, I don't believe you could do anything like that without going to the metadata api, or potentially running a batch that queries for List Views based on who created and updates the name. You cannot add another field to the dropdown.